# http PUT and DELETE using JSR 286 serveResource()

Tags: portlet, jsr286

I'm making a ajax request with type:'DELETE' but somehow the request is not going inside the ServeResources(request,response) method (overridden from GenericPortlet class).

does anyone has an idea that why "Delete" and "Put" are not working with portal application(JSR 286) and How to get rid of that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

HTTP PUT/DELETE are some what protected methods, most of the web/application servers disable these methods by default, that could be the reason why you are not seeing your requests on server side. AFAIK it is independent of portal environment and handled by web/application server. You need to do some configuration changes on your server.

Comment: Thanks, I checked my server settings but it seems good ,it has all the http-method defines there, I am  getting "Error 405: Http method DELETE is not supported by this URL"